# How to validation CSV import in magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, csv, validation

I have Create custom CSV import functionally. But How to check which row data is blank and i want to show error like :- **Required field is empty in row(s)**. So Please help me how to check which row is blank in import CSV.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create import.xml file and handle all validation logic in php file
You can refer to this article https://magecomp.com/blog/import-csv-file-to-custom-table-magento-2/